# C# timer with long tick event

Tags: c#, timer

I have a Windows Form application in C# for controlling 3 external devices. I am wondering how to implement the following task.

Every second, I need to perform a check-on on all three devices, independently from each other. If the results are within a certain range, nothing happens, but if they are not, I have to do a temperature correction on the corresponding device(s) which takes 10 seconds, i.e. much longer than the checking time interval. It is pivotal to wait out this 10 seconds so the new equilibrium temperature can settle, and continue with the checking only afterwards. However, correcting one temperature should not block the checking of the other devices.

The question is: what is the best way to do this? I suppose I should create 3 threads for the three devices, but how to pause (and restart afterwards!) the checking to wait out the settling time?

Comment: @RufusL, _However, correcting one temperature should not block the checking of the other devices._

Comment: `Timer` controls have `Start` and `Stop` methods that can be used to "pause" them. So in the `Tick` event, if the `CheckTemperature` method returns `false`, then you could `Stop` the timer, call the `CorrectTemperature` method, wait for it to return, and then `Start` the timer again. Showing the code that's not working would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not changing your timer interval, instead when you know a device is in calibration (hopefully based on a reply and not just a blindly sent command), start a `Stopwatch` object.  Later you can check `Elapsed.Seconds` on that stopwatch to see whether your settling time has ended.

Unlike a `Timer`, a running `Stopwatch` requires no resources at all.

If you are using `async`/`await` to communicate with your devices, then a single timer would be sufficient for all three.  Once per second, check if each device is in calibration and if not, transmit your "check" message.  After all three are transmitted, await the three responses.